# tab pane not clickable?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a tab pane not clickable, is a form, then i only want to go that pane if the first form is complete, but i couldn't make it unclickable, not even with `unbind()` can someone help me?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#datospersonales" data-toggle="tab">
                            Datos Personales
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#datosgenerales" id="ficha-dg">
                            Datos Generales
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content" style="min-height: 300px;">

                    <!-- TAB DATOS PERSONALES -->

                    <div id="datospersonales" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                        <div class="row pt-15">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                                <label for="newrut" class="control-label">Rut:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="newrut" name="newrut" class="form-control"
                                    data-inputmask="'mask':'99.999.999-*'" datamask required
                                    placeholder="__.___.___-_">
                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            <!-- FINAL TAB DATOS PERSONALES -->

            <!-- TAB DATOS GENERALES -->

            <div id="datosgenerales" class="tab pane fade">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery code i tried

```
$('#ficha-dg').unbind('click');
```

Comment: What framework are you using that is making it clickable?  It's quite possible that the binding is not on that particular element.  Also, the element you are targeting is an `a` tag.  No javascript binding is making the `href="#blah"` work.  That's native behaviour.

Comment: @Taplar jquery,bootstrap and an inputmask, nothing more

Comment: Please make a [mcve] of the behaviour that is happening that you want to *not* happen.

Comment: The default behavior of clicking on an `<a>` is to go to the `href`. If you want to stop this, you need to bind a click handler that calls `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the other tabs disabled until the first one is complete.

For example:

Write a class to disable the tabs:

```
.disabled-tab {
  cursor: disabled;
}
```

Then we want to write some jQuery to remove the class when the first tab is complete:

```
var fields = document.getElementById('newrut');

if (!newrut) {
 if ('.nav-tabs li').hasClass('disabled') {
   $(this).removeClass('disabled');
 }
}
```

Haven't tested it but something along these lines should work.